# WPF: Keep TreeView expanded after ICollectionView Refresh

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF application and in one of the view I am using TreeView.

TreeView structure is like ***Parent Node >> Child Node >> Grand Child***.

I have implemented drag drop functionality so that **Grand Child** Node can be drag and dropped **between Child nodes of Same Parent**.

I have an **ObservableCollection of a model class** in my viewmodel and TreeView is using that ObservableCollection through **ICollectionView** (CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView()).

Whenever I am moving grandchild between child nodes, I am doing ICollcetionView.Refresh() so that I can see updated UI.

Now after doing ICollcetionView.Refresh(), TreeView is not remaining in expanded state.

I want to keep nodes expanded on which I am doing drap-drop.

So for example I have,

Parent 1 >> Child 1 >> GrandChild 1  and
Parent 1 >> Child 2 >> GrandChild 2.

Now If I am moving GrandChild 2 to under Child 1  then,

**Parent 1 >> Child 1 and 
Parent 1 >> Child 2**

should remain expanded even after ICollectionView.Refresh()

Comment: If the parent node of your treeview is databound to an underlying object then you can bind the 'isexpanded' property of the node, and control it from your own code.

Comment: Parent Nodes and Child nodes gives an item of type CollectionViewGroup. 
GrandChildNode is my model class.